# how can I add custom favicon to some websites without favicon in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[fixed tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlkTS.jpg)

As shown in the figure, some websites don't have favicons. So, Using the fixed tab make them messy.

Comment: There are at least several answers that show how to set the favicon of a tab using an extension so I think it should be easy to find. In short, use a content script to add a `<link>` element with rel="icon".

Comment: `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh`  is what I want

Comment: Good. You can inspect the source code of any extension in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm . thx, me me da~

Answer (score 0):

You can add favicon to your website by following method

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>{$title}</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```